# Using AlamoFire to fetch data to populate UITableView based on UISearchBar value

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

Unlike many JSON requests, instead of filtering a long pre-determined JSON, I intend to send a JSON request (using AlamoFire) based on what is typed into a Search Bar, thus fetching the JSON to be parsed (with SwiftyJSON) to fill the UITableView

[image]

What I'd like to do is to use the searchTerm (typed into the searchbar) to send an AlamoFire request to [Geonames](http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?formatted=true&q=burpham&maxRows=3&username=demo) using the searchTerm in the query field of geonames API request. i.e.

> http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?formatted=true&q=(searchTerm)&maxRows=3&username=demo

What I essentially cannot do is send the request AFTER filling out the Search Bar, and therefore populate the table with that data.

Below is my current code (which populates the table upon the view loading with parsed JSON data with a request for *"burpham"*

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class SearchAddLocationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{

@IBOutlet weak var tblJSON: UITableView!

@IBOutlet weak var searchbarValue: UISearchBar!

weak open var delegate: UISearchBarDelegate?

var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

public func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) // called when text ends editing
{
    callAlamo(searchTerm: searchbarValue.text!)
}

func callAlamo(searchTerm: String)
{
    Alamofire.request("http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=\(searchTerm)&maxRows=5&username=garethallenstringer").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

            if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["geonames"].arrayObject {
                self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            }
            if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
                self.tblJSON.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addLocProtoCell")!
    var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = dict["name"] as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dict["countryName"] as? String
    return cell
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return arrRes.count
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to listen `func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)` method of UISearchBar delegate for populating your `UITableView`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet private weak var searchBar: UISearchBar?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.searchBar?.delegate = self
    }

    //MARK: UISearchBarDelegate methods
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
       //You can do your request via Alamofire to populate tableView
    }
}
```

UPDATE #1

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class SearchAddLocationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate
{

    @IBOutlet weak var tblJSON: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var searchbarValue: UISearchBar!

    var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.searchbarValue.delegate = self
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) { // called when text ends editing
    {
        callAlamo(searchTerm: searchbarValue.text!)
    }

    func callAlamo(searchTerm: String)
    {
        Alamofire.request("http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON?q=\(searchTerm)&maxRows=5&username=garethallenstringer").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["geonames"].arrayObject {
                    self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                }
                if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
                    self.tblJSON.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "addLocProtoCell")!
        var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = dict["name"] as? String
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dict["countryName"] as? String
        return cell
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return arrRes.count
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: So I see from this that the `searchBarTextDidEndEditing` takes the actual `UISearchBar` as a parameter, would that mean that any string typed by a user into the Search Bar is of that type?

Comment: `func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {}` will be called after user will finish editing of searchBar. UISearchBar has a property `text`, so you can get searchBar current text like that: 
`func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        print(searchBar.text)
}`

Comment: So in order to add the UISearchBarDelegate, one must simply have `    weak open var delegate: UISearchBarDelegate?` at the top along with other initialisers/outlets? I believe I've correctly added the methods, but nothing happens when the Search button on the software keyboard is pressed, despite a call to a function named `callAlamo` which takes a string (`searchBar.text`) from the `searchBarDidEndEditing` function. I shall update my question to reflect the changes in code.

Comment: Nope, you don't need to have `weak open var delegate: UISearchBarDelegate?`in your code. Just subscribe to `UISearchBarDelegate` of your `searchbarValue` in `viewDidLoad()` like that:
`self.searchbarValue.delegate = self`

Comment: Does this now mean that I need to have `UISearchBarDelegate` (as well as `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`) when initialising the class? I had it before as a Delegate to the UITableView - is that incorrect?

Comment: Yep, you are right. I've updated my answer with working solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144932/discussion-between-michaelas-and-taras-chernyshenko).